# How do I check for internet using Moya and RxSwift?

Tags: swift4, rx-swift, connectivity, internet-connection, moya

As far as I understand **Alamofire** is pulled in with built in **Reachability**, so my own handler would look something like:

```
import Alamofire

let reachabilityManager = NetworkReachabilityManager()
reachabilityManager.listener = { status in

switch status {

case .notReachable:
 print("The network is not reachable")
 self.onInternetDisconnection()

case .unknown :
 print("It is unknown whether the network is reachable")
 self.onInternetDisconnection() // not sure what to do for this case

case .reachable(.ethernetOrWiFi):
 print("The network is reachable over the WiFi connection")
 self.onInternetConnection()

case .reachable(.wwan):
 print("The network is reachable over the WWAN connection")
 self.onInternetConnection()

 }
}
```

I'm making a request with:

```
let provider = MoyaProvider<MyMoyaRequest>()
let token = provider.request(.start(
    username:self.email.value, 
    password: self.password.value) { result in

    switch result { 
    case let .success(moyaResponse):
        //handle success
    case let .failure(error):
        //handle failure
    }
}
```

So if I want to have connectivity checked before every **Moya** Request is made what is the best way to go about it?

1. Write an extension for one of Moyas internals to check first
2. Use the Moya plugin (prepare) to check
3. Some fancy pants other way so far unthought of...

I specifically do **not** want to add a reachability check to every single API call, for readability reasons. But I am interested in hearing about methods previously used.

Thank-you for any assistance you can offer.

Answer (score 2):

> I specifically do not want to add a reachability check to every single API call

It might be a reasonable decision to wrap all you API calls into some service. For example how I did it in my last app:

```
public protocol NetworkServiceType: class {
    /// Cancellable request
    func observableRequest<T,C>(api: AnyApi<T>, cancel: Observable<C>, headers: [AUApi.Header: String], indicator: ActivityRelay?, logs: NetworkServiceLogs, timeout: TimeInterval, queue: DispatchQueue) -> Observable<Output<T>>
}
```

As you can see the network service has a single function that is able accept all the necessary parameters. And when you wrap all your requests into a single function - you can add everything you want inside this function. Even reachability check!

> I want to have connectivity checked before every Moya Request is made

There are some ways to do it:

1. I'd create a shared reactive reachability service and inject this service in network service. So, before every Moya Request you can call `withLatestFrom` and get the latest status from your reachability service.
2. You can create reachability service for each request and delete it after request is completed.

I'd love show you how to create the 2nd variant. The first thing we need is some `ReachabilityInformer`:

```
final class ReachabilityInformer: Disposable {

    private lazy var networkReachabilityManager: NetworkReachabilityManager? = NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.google.com")
    private lazy var relayNetworkReachable = PublishRelay<Bool>()

    init() {
        switch networkReachabilityManager {
        case .none:
            relayNetworkReachable.accept(false)
        case .some(let manager):
            manager.listener = { [weak informer = self] status in
                switch status {
                case .notReachable:
                    informer?.relayNetworkReachable.accept(false)
                case .unknown:
                    break
                case .reachable:
                    informer?.relayNetworkReachable.accept(true)
                }
            }
        }
        networkReachabilityManager?.startListening()
    }

    func observableReachable() -> Observable<Bool> {
        return relayNetworkReachable
            .asObservable()
            .distinctUntilChanged()
    }

    func dispose() {
        networkReachabilityManager?.stopListening()
        networkReachabilityManager?.listener = nil
        networkReachabilityManager = nil
    }
}
```

It should conform to `Disposable` because it will be used by `using` operator.

So, how to use it:

```
Observable<Bool>
    .using({ ReachabilityInformer() }, observableFactory: { (informer: ReachabilityInformer) -> Observable<Bool> in
        return informer.observableReachable()
    })
```

The request should be started using this `Observable`. If connections exists `true` you should `flatMap` to your Moya Request. If it is `false`, then you should return a failure or throw an error. When request is completed, `using` operator will make sure that the `ReachabilityInformer` is deallocated.

P.S. Not tested, just some information to think about

Comment: Hello @iWheelBuy, I am little confused about above code could you please explain

Comment: @MeSolutionanalysts Sorry, I don't have enough time to provide you with a detailed answer.

Comment: I've added `startListening()` and `stopListening()` calls, does't work otherwise